# Deploying Hyperledger Fabric organizations in multiple hosts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

I have been struggling while trying to build a fabric 2.0 network with organizations spread in multiple hosts. The official [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/channel_update_tutorial.html) explains how to deploy two organizations (**org1** and **org2**) using docker, and using **configtxlator** tool to add new orgs and peers.

The issue here is that in all documentation examples, organizations run in the same docker-engine host, which misses the whole point of **distributed systems**. Recently I found this blog post that endorses everything I am struggling with:

https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

In this post, the author recommends using **docker-swarm** to create an overlay network that creates a distributed network among multiple Docker daemon hosts.

However, **this post is from 2018**, and I am wondering if this is still the best solution available? Or if **Kubernetes**, nowadays, would be the go for choice to create this overlay network?

**ps:** this network I am building is for academic purposes and research only, related to my PhD. studies.

Comment: You can refer to these links which can help you in running a Hyperledger Fabric network using Kubernetes https://github.com/aidtechnology/lf-k8s-hlf-webinar, https://accenture.github.io/blog/2019/06/25/hl-fabric-meets-kubernetes.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `docker-swarm` to deploy the network. `docker-swarm` is quite easy when compared to `kubernetes`. Since you mentioned that it is for academic purpose and research only then `docker-swarm` is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For sure I will give a try with docker-swarm. :D

Answer (score 0):

Or you if want to deploy the production-grade hyperledger fabric you can use open source tool BAF, [Blockchain Automation Framework](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/blockchain-automation-framework) which is an automation framework for rapidly and consistently deploying production-ready DLT platforms to cloud infrastructure.